# Can I identify ongoing web request on linux?

Tags: linux, perl, websocket

I have a perl Catalyst application that uses websockets. From time to time I have to restart the app for bugfixes and features.
For this I change nginx conf, reload nginx and start parallel app with new code. Then restart the old app and kill the intermediate app.
The problem with this chain of logic is, I might kill an ongoing request. All new request are handled nicely, that is not the problem.
So my question is, can I somehow detect, that socket has an ongoing request?

Or, should I use a poor man's solution, and before kill wait for 30s?

Nginx relevant part(live):

```
upstream backend {
    ip_hash;

    server unix:/tmp/frontend.socket;
    server unix:/tmp/frontend_redundant.socket down;
}
```

(restart):

```
upstream backend {
    ip_hash;

    server unix:/tmp/frontend.socket down;
    server unix:/tmp/frontend_redundant.socket;
}
```

For app restart I use Daemon::Control start/stop.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [nginx guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#control), the command `nginx -s quit` (or kill -QUIT) does a graceful shutdown which waits for the worker processes to finish serving current requests.

Comment: Hm, it is all dandy, but the app is running on FastCGI, so I doubt that nginx knows anything about fastcgi worker processes. Nginx is only proxy. Also I only reload nginx conf, so the nginx is always up.